# How To Fetch Data From Markdown File and Display it as a HTML input Form

Tags: php, python, html, node.js, markdown

Is there any way to fetch data from markdown file and display it as a input form.

For the example lets say i have markdown file called data.md like this

```
---
title: "the data" // input form title
image: "the data" // input form image attachment
---
//text area 
---
```

And then with a bunch of code the data from markdown above will be convert as an input an HTML form.

Kindly show me where should i start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [frontmatter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/frontmatter).

Assuming you're serving your `.md` file at `/docs/example.md`. Try something like this

```
$.GET('/docs/example.md').then(function(content){
    var parsed = frontmatter(content, { safeLoad: true });
    $('input[name=title]').val(parsed.data['title']);
});
```